# How do I re-use components in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS grid like so:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    ...
});
```

I'd like to be able to re-use this grid so that I can have it multiple instances of it that all act independently. Is the only way to do this is by using `Ext.extend`, or is there another way? I don't really need to extend it, I just need to be able to create multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really just need two grid instances, then create another one as Upper Stage said.

If you need to share a config among multiple grids, you could save the config as a separate JS object that you then pass into the grid constructor each time you create one.

```
var myCfg = { ... };
var grid1 = new Ext.GridPanel(Ext.apply(myCfg, { /* other options */ }));
var grid2 = new Ext.GridPanel(Ext.apply(myCfg, { /* other options */ }));
```

If you are going to reuse the grid with a particular configuration across your app or in multiple apps, then a subclass may be the best way to go.

[This tutorial](http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Extending_Ext_for_Newbies) reviews several different methods for reusing functionality and would be a good starting point for you to decide what approach best suits your needs (if you need something beyond two basic instances).

Comment: I do this sometimes. Define the config first, then re-use it to create multiple objects.

Comment: Thanks, I found the tutorial on my own which answered my question, but you linked it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Component#cloneConfig() perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply instantiate new objects?

```
var anotherGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ext has decent support for subclassing. This means you can extend the standard grid and instantiate that:

```
Foo = {};
Foo.BarGrid = function(config) {
  Foo.BarGrid.superclass.constructor.call(this, config); //call the default grid constructor
}

Ext.extend(Foo.BarGrid, Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
  //grid config
});

var grid = new Foo.BarGrid({/*minimal config*/});
```

You can even register your own xtype and use that instead of `new`ing it:

```
Ext.reg('foobargrid', Foo.BarGrid);

var pane = new Ext.TabPanel({
  items: [{xtype: 'foobargrid'}]
});
```

**EDIT** Misread the question. Since you obviously know about `Ext.extend` sharing the config, as suggested by bmoeskau, might just do the trick for you.